# WCF Named pipe configured in app.config does not work

Tags: c#, wcf, client, named-pipes

So I have my named pipe declared like this:

```
        DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceHandler> pipeFactory;pipeFactory =
              new DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceHandler>(
                  myCallbacks,
                 new NetNamedPipeBinding(),
                 new EndpointAddress(
                    "net.pipe://localhost/Server"));
        pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

(THIS WORKS)

I want to put the configuration in the app.config file so I go there and make it:

```
<client>
  <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/Server" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
    bindingConfiguration="netNamedPipeBinding" contract="WCFClient.IServiceHandler"
    name="ClientEndpointinClient" />
.
.
.
```

And then remove the config from the declaration:

```
        pipeFactory =
              new DuplexChannelFactory<IServiceHandler>(
                  myCallbacks);
        pipeProxy = pipeFactory.CreateChannel();
```

Don't worry about callbacks, they are well declared.
But when I try to do the Create channel, it says that the endpoint is null...

What am I missing?

Comment: Don't you ahve to use the endpoint name "CleintEndpointClient" somewhere?

Comment: It is in my server configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the Endpoint name as a `string`, or an `EndpointAddress` instance, into the `CreateChannel()` method call.

Comment: It's going to be pretty hard to avoid according to your code that uses channels...

Comment: Oh true I forgot the configuration name in the channel